# How to customize tokenization in SAP HANA full text search index

Tags: customization, tokenize, hana

With SAP HANA you can do text analysis, full text search and even sentiment analysis.

**What are the options for customizing the tokenization in SAP HANA?**

I know that I can create a custom dictionary for special words. e.g. I can make HANA recognize 'stack overflow' as a single entity / token.

But sometimes HANA creates tokens out of multiple words which are not one token / entity e.g. 'SAP experience' here I want 2 tokens 'SAP' and 'experience' (not 'SAP experience)

So how to customize the tokenization (other than custom dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this information and thought I'd pass it along in case it helps.

Take a look at the numerous parameters available to customize the indexing of text in HANA.. To view the configuration of a full-text index, you use the SYS.FULLTEXT_INDEXES view.  What value do you have for PHRASE INDEX RATIO?

full source: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/cc/c504cebb571014badd88b622a24cae/content.htm?frameset=/en/f5/ceb3d471bf4ec0bf5a77351c1f035d/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/fd/c71ac6a10b43cd97ff1bee7a3c3aab/plain.htm&node_id=21&show_children=false